# How to create child window in electron-react application?

Tags: reactjs, electron

When i open the application it starts with login form. I want to close that window on succes login and open another one with main page. How can i do it in context of using react app for UI? I need to run another react app or i can somehow use same app and just open app in other windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Electron window runs in a separate renderer process, so you can't use the same *instance* of your React app in another window. You can theoretically use the same app, as in open a new window with another instance of the same app and simply display a different view.